URDF seems to be not genuine when running with ros2_control and custom hardware interface
Whenever I start my robot I get an error regarding a not genuine URDF file, which causes the controller_manager not to spawn. I have already tried comparing my URDF with the diffbot demo but can't find the issues. Has anyone else ran into this issue? I am using ROS2 Iron. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I have figured out that everything works fine when I substitute my own URDF that gets entered into RSP with the diffbot.urdf.xacro, so there must be something wrong with my URDF surely. I just can't find it.

robot.urdf.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="robot">
    <!-- Robot Description -->
    <xacro:include filename="material_colors.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="robot_description.urdf.xacro" />
    <xacro:include filename="ros2_control.xacro" />
</robot>

ERROR:
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.030013872] [controller_manager]: Subscribing to '/robot_description' topic for robot description.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.030208397] [controller_manager]: update rate is 50 Hz
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.036464472] [controller_manager]: RT kernel is recommended for better performance
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.075097216] [controller_manager]: Received robot description from topic.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.075585846] [resource_manager]: Loading hardware 'HardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.076984075] [resource_manager]: Initialize hardware 'HardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.077541023] [resource_manager]: Successful initialization of hardware 'HardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.077736973] [resource_manager]: 'configure' hardware 'HardwareInterface' 
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.077771337] [DiffDriveRoboteqHardware]: Configuring ...please wait...
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1715690640.077893797] [DiffDriveRoboteqHardware]: Unable to open port /dev/ttyACM0.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.079828587] [DiffDriveRoboteqHardware]: Serial Port /dev/ttyACM0 is not open.
[ros2_control_node-1] [INFO] [1715690640.079860086] [resource_manager]: Failed to 'configure' hardware 'HardwareInterface'
[ros2_control_node-1] [ERROR] [1715690640.080009969] [controller_manager]: The published robot description file (urdf) seems not to be genuine. The following error was caught:could not create service: rcl node's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/node.c:446
[spawner-3] [INFO] [1715691449.987508547] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist
[spawner-3] [ERROR] [1715691452.006009120] [spawner_joint_state_broadcaster]: Controller manager not available

robot_description.urdf.xacro:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

    <!-- Base Link -->
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/base_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="light_taupe"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/base_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
        
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.047144 -0.0028345 -0.41478" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.59" />
            <inertia ixx="20.641" ixy="0.00016992" ixz="-0.49423" iyy="6.5187" iyz="0.00055771" izz="24.879" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Left Motor Wheel Link -->
    <joint name="Left_motor_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.77784 0.723 -1.3493" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Left_motor_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Left_motor_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Left_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="ash_gray"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Left_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-1.75365585441956E-07 0.0270006737216059 -1.93349436128365E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="2.81598571989199" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0184877495766498" ixy="2.29761900848141E-07" ixz="-2.57088871335598E-08" iyy="0.0301863785104543" iyz="1.93292070690171E-07" izz="0.0184876895395364" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Left Swivel Link -->
    <joint name="Left_swivel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="0.96561 0.75 -1.084" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Left_swivel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Left_swivel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_gray"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.0618449265724237 1.49015045774082E-09 -0.158180113097024" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="3.7827012394741" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0393150604894362" ixy="1.81657492835183E-10" ixz="-0.0153011144840003" iyy="0.0361500925653868" iyz="-4.69410806455382E-10" izz="0.0278648244978593" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Left Swivel Wheel Link -->
    <joint name="Left_swivel_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.15614 -0.017798 -0.28963" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="Left_swivel_link" />
        <child link="Left_swivel_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Left_swivel_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_blue"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Left_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-8.42359524355629E-08 0.0177982203392603 -1.46493464531217E-06" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.01679969602072" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0140382716247924" ixy="2.15723669563332E-08" ixz="9.27403982855476E-19" iyy="0.0261356546025606" iyz="6.87396277095084E-09" izz="0.0140382716247924" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Right Motor Wheel Link -->
    <joint name="Right_motor_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.77784 -0.72355 -1.3493" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Right_motor_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Right_motor_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Right_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="ash_gray"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Right_motor_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-1.75365585441956E-07 -0.0270006737216059 -1.93349436128365E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="2.81598571989199" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0184877495766498" ixy="2.29761900848141E-07" ixz="-2.57088871335598E-08" iyy="0.0301863785104543" iyz="1.93292070690171E-07" izz="0.0184876895395364" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Right Swivel Link -->
    <joint name="Right_swivel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="0.96561 -0.75 -1.084" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="base_link" />
        <child link="Right_swivel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Right_swivel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_gray"/>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="-0.0618449235933072 -1.4860177088849E-08 -0.158180125308815" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="3.78270123947423" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0393150604894546" ixy="1.81658250750189E-10" ixz="-0.015301114483994" iyy="0.0361500925653877" iyz="-4.6940988688316E-10" izz="0.0278648244978431" />
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Right Swivel Wheel Link -->
    <joint name="Right_swivel_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
        <origin xyz="-0.15614 0.017798 -0.28963" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <parent link="Right_swivel_link" />
        <child link="Right_swivel_wheel_link" />
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
    </joint>

    <link name="Right_swivel_wheel_link">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="pale_blue"/>
        </visual>
        
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/Right_swivel_wheel_link.STL"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="1.17173987068675E-06 -0.0177982367124008 -8.99404833498707E-07" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <mass value="1.01679969602083" />
            <inertia ixx="0.0140382716247939" ixy="1.96477435121725E-09" ixz="-8.49248892198181E-19" iyy="0.0261356546025633" iyz="2.25556660675932E-08" izz="0.0140382716247939" />
        </inertial>
    </link>
</robot>

rsp.launch.py:
def generate_launch_description():
    # Check if we're told to use sim time
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
    use_ros2_control = LaunchConfiguration('use_ros2_control')

    # Process the URDF file
    pkg_path = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot_description'))
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_path,'xacro','**robot**.urdf.xacro')
    # robot_description_config = xacro.process_file(xacro_file).toxml()
    robot_description_config = Command(['xacro ', xacro_file, ' use_ros2_control:=', use_ros2_control, ' sim_mode:=', use_sim_time])
    
    # Create a robot_state_publisher node
    params = {'robot_description': robot_description_config, 'use_sim_time': use_sim_time}
    node_robot_state_publisher = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[params]
    )

    # Launch!
    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_sim_time',
            default_value='false',
            description='Use sim time if true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            'use_ros2_control',
            default_value='true',
            description='Use ros2_control if true'),

        node_robot_state_publisher
    ])

EDIT: ADDED rviz.launch.py
rviz.launch.py:
def generate_launch_description():
    package_name = 'robot_description'
    pkg_share = get_package_share_directory(package_name)
    
    xacro_file = os.path.join(pkg_share,'xacro',robot.urdf.xacro)
    robot_description = xacro.process_file(xacro_file)

    rviz_filename = 'robot.rviz'
    rviz_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz', rviz_filename)

    gui_argument = DeclareLaunchArgument(
            name='gui',
            default_value='true',
            description='Whether to launch nodes with GUI.'
    )

    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        condition=IfCondition(
            EqualsSubstitution(LaunchConfiguration('gui'), 'true')
        )
    )

    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        name='robot_state_publisher',
        output='screen',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': robot_description.toxml()}]
    )

    rviz_node = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',
        arguments=['-d', rviz_path, '-f', 'base_link']
    )

    return LaunchDescription([
        gui_argument,
        joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
        robot_state_publisher_node,
        rviz_node
    ])

EDIT: Added Hardware Component
in progress hardware component:
#include "diffdrive_roboteq/diffdrive_roboteq.hpp"

#include "hardware_interface/lexical_casts.hpp"
#include "hardware_interface/types/hardware_interface_type_values.hpp"
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

namespace diffdrive_roboteq
{
    // Here, you should initialize all member variables and process the parameters from the info argument.
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_init(const hardware_interface::HardwareInfo & info)
        {
            if (
                hardware_interface::SystemInterface::on_init(info) !=
                hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS)
            {
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
            }

            conf_.serial_port = info_.hardware_parameters["serial_port"];
            conf_.baud_rate = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["baud_rate"]);
            conf_.closed_loop = (info_.hardware_parameters["closed_loop"] == "true");
            conf_.diff_drive_mode = (info_.hardware_parameters["diff_drive_mode"] == "true");
            conf_.wheel_circumference = hardware_interface::stod(info_.hardware_parameters["wheel_circumference"]);
            conf_.track_width = hardware_interface::stod(info_.hardware_parameters["track_width"]);
            conf_.max_rpm = hardware_interface::stod(info_.hardware_parameters["max_rpm"]);
            conf_.frequency = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["frequency"]);
            conf_.cmd_vel_topic = info_.hardware_parameters["cmd_vel_topic"];

            conf_.left_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["left_wheel_name"];
            conf_.right_wheel_name = info_.hardware_parameters["right_wheel_name"];
            conf_.timeout_ms = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["timeout_ms"]);
            conf_.enc_counts_per_rev = std::stoi(info_.hardware_parameters["enc_counts_per_rev"]);
            
            hw_positions_.resize(info_.joints.size(), std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
            hw_velocities_.resize(info_.joints.size(), std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
            hw_commands_.resize(info_.joints.size(), std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());

            for (const hardware_interface::ComponentInfo & joint : info_.joints)
            {
                if (joint.command_interfaces.size() != 1)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' has %zu command interfaces found. 1 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.command_interfaces.size());
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.command_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' have %s command interfaces found. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.command_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.state_interfaces.size() != 2)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' has %zu state interface. 2 expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.state_interfaces.size());
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.state_interfaces[0].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' have '%s' as first state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.state_interfaces[0].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION);
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }

                if (joint.state_interfaces[1].name != hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY)
                {
                RCLCPP_FATAL(
                    rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),
                    "Joint '%s' have '%s' as second state interface. '%s' expected.", joint.name.c_str(),
                    joint.state_interfaces[1].name.c_str(), hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY);
                return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
                }
            }

            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
        }

    // Implement export_state_interfaces and export_command_interfaces methods where interfaces that hardware offers are defined. 
    // As a reminder, the full interface names have structure <joint_name>/<interface_type>.
    std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::export_state_interfaces()
    {
        std::vector<hardware_interface::StateInterface> state_interfaces;
        for (auto i = 0u; i < info_.joints.size(); i++)
        {
            state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
            info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_POSITION, &hw_positions_[i]));
            state_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::StateInterface(
            info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &hw_velocities_[i]));
        }

        return state_interfaces;

    }

    // Implement export_state_interfaces and export_command_interfaces methods where interfaces that hardware offers are defined. 
    // As a reminder, the full interface names have structure <joint_name>/<interface_type>.
    std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::export_command_interfaces()
    {
        std::vector<hardware_interface::CommandInterface> command_interfaces;
        for (auto i = 0u; i < info_.joints.size(); i++)
        {
            command_interfaces.emplace_back(hardware_interface::CommandInterface(
            info_.joints[i].name, hardware_interface::HW_IF_VELOCITY, &hw_commands_[i]));
        }

        return command_interfaces;
    }

    /**
    * @brief Configures the hardware communication.
    * 
    * This method sets up the communication to the hardware and prepares it for activation.
    * It initializes the serial port with the specified settings such as port name and baud rate.
    * 
    * @param previous_state The previous lifecycle state of the hardware component.
    * @return CallbackReturn Returns a status indicating the success or failure of the configuration process.
    */
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_configure(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {
        // Log a message indicating that the configuration process is starting
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Configuring ...please wait...");
        
        try {
            // Set up the serial port with the specified configuration parameters
            ser_.setPort(conf_.serial_port);
            ser_.setBaudrate(conf_.baud_rate);
            serial::Timeout timeout = serial::Timeout::simpleTimeout(1000);
            ser_.setTimeout(timeout);
            ser_.open();
        } catch (serial::IOException &e) {
            // If an exception occurs during port setup (e.g., unable to open port), log an error message and shutdown the ROS node
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Unable to open port " << conf_.serial_port << ".");
            rclcpp::shutdown();
        }

        if (ser_.isOpen()) {
            // If the port is open, log a message indicating successful initialization
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " initialized.");
        } else {
            // If the port is not open, log a message indicating failure and shutdown the ROS node
            RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " is not open.");
            rclcpp::shutdown();
            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }


    /**
    * @brief Cleans up the hardware communication.
    * 
    * This method closes the serial port to clean up the hardware communication interface.
    * 
    * @param previous_state The previous lifecycle state of the hardware component.
    * @return CallbackReturn Returns a status indicating the success or failure of the cleanup process.
    */
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_cleanup(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {
        // Log a message indicating that the cleanup process is starting
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Cleaning up ...please wait...");
        
        try {
            // Check if the serial port is open and close it if so
            if (ser_.isOpen()) {
                ser_.close();
                RCLCPP_INFO_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " closed.");
            } else {
                // Log a warning if the serial port was not open
                RCLCPP_WARN_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial Port " << conf_.serial_port << " was not open.");
            }
        } catch (const serial::IOException &e) {
            // Log an error if an exception occurs during the closing process
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Error while closing serial port: " << e.what());
        }

        // Log a message indicating successful cleanup
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Successfully cleaned up!");

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }


    // Implement the on_activate method where hardware “power” is enabled.
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_activate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Activating ...please wait...");
        
        // Check if the serial port is open
        if (!ser_.isOpen()) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial port is not open. Unable to activate.");
            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        // Stop motors and configure hardware
        try {
            // Stop motors
            ser_.write("!G 1 0\r");
            ser_.write("!G 2 0\r");
            ser_.write("!S 1 0\r");
            ser_.write("!S 2 0\r");
            ser_.flush();

            // Enable watchdog timer
            ser_.write("^RWD 1000\r");
            ser_.flush();

            // Set motor operating mode
            if (!conf_.closed_loop) {
                ser_.write("^MMOD 1 0\r");
                ser_.write("^MMOD 2 0\r");
                ser_.flush();
            } else {
                ser_.write("^MMOD 1 1\r");
                ser_.write("^MMOD 2 1\r");
                ser_.flush();
            }

            // Set encoder counts
            std::stringstream right_enccmd;
            std::stringstream left_enccmd;
            right_enccmd << "^EPPR 1 " << 1024 << "\r";
            left_enccmd << "^EPPR 2 " << 1024 << "\r";
            ser_.write(right_enccmd.str());
            ser_.write(left_enccmd.str());
            ser_.flush();
        } catch (const serial::IOException &e) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR_STREAM(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Error while configuring hardware: " << e.what());
            return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::ERROR;
        }

        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Successfully activated!");

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }

    // Implement the on_deactivate method, which does the opposite of on_activate.
    hardware_interface::CallbackReturn DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::on_deactivate(const rclcpp_lifecycle::State & /*previous_state*/)
    {
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Deactivating ...please wait...");
        // TODO
        RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Successfully deactivated!");

        return hardware_interface::CallbackReturn::SUCCESS;
    }

    // Implement the read method getting the states from the hardware and storing them to internal variables defined in export_state_interfaces.
    hardware_interface::return_type DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::read(const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & period)
    {
        // Check if the serial port is open
        if (!ser_.isOpen()) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial port is not open. Unable to activate.");
            return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
        }
        
        // TODO
        return hardware_interface::return_type::OK;
    }

    // Implement write method that commands the hardware based on the values stored in internal variables defined in export_command_interfaces.
    hardware_interface::return_type diffdrive_roboteq ::DiffDriveRoboteqHardware::write(
    const rclcpp::Time & /*time*/, const rclcpp::Duration & /*period*/)
    {
        // Check if the serial port is open
        if (!ser_.isOpen()) {
            RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"), "Serial port is not open. Unable to activate.");
            return hardware_interface::return_type::ERROR;
        }
        
        std::stringstream cmd_str;
        
        if(conf_.closed_loop) {
            // wheel speed (m/s)
            float left_speed  = hw_commands_[0];
            float right_speed = hw_commands_[1];

            // motor speed (rpm)
            int32_t left_rpm  = left_speed  *60.0 / conf_.wheel_circumference;
            int32_t right_rpm = right_speed *60.0 / conf_.wheel_circumference;

            RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("DiffDriveRoboteqHardware"),"[ROBOTEQ] left: %9d right: %9d", left_rpm, right_rpm);
            cmd_str << "!S 1"
                    << " " << left_rpm << "_"
                    << "!S 2"
                    << " " << right_rpm << "_";
        }
        else {
            cmd_str << "!G 1"
                    << " " << hw_commands_[0] << "_"
                    << "!G 2"
                    << " " << hw_commands_[1] << "_";
        }
        ser_.write(cmd_str.str());
        ser_.flush();
    }
} // namespace diffdrive_roboteq
#include "pluginlib/class_list_macros.hpp"
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(diffdrive_roboteq::DiffDriveRoboteqHardware, hardware_interface::SystemInterface)
```


Can you try check_urdf first, then robot_state_publisher_gui like we do in our examples?

check_urdf checks out:
robot name is: robot
---------- Successfully Parsed XML ---------------
I don't know anything about a robot_state_pub_gui but I've tried using joint_state_pub_gui and that still gives the same problem.

what do you mean? If you use the view_robot.launch.py launch file, you don't use ros2_control at all. This means if you already get the error there, then the issue is within your base URDF. (I don't know what check_urdf does check at all).

I have a very similar launch file that also launches rsp, joint_state_pub_gui and rviz just like view_robot.launch.py, which I have added above. This launches Rviz and perfectly displays the robot based on the URDF.

have you seen that your hardware component cannot be configured? I'm not sure why this should be related to the URDF-error, but who knows. Can you try to setup the GenericSystem instead? See example_2 (mock_hardware) as an example.

Using the GenericSystem I have none of the abovementioned issues anymore. The issue must then lie in the hardware component. For reference I have added the hardware component as well.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Have you seen that your hardware component cannot be configured?
Hardware components do not have an executor or spawn a node. In the failure cases, you call
rclcpp::shutdown();

and this will break the controller_manager (the ressource manager of it loads the hardware component plugins) -> I think this is where the rcl-context error comes from. Don't ask me why this comes in an exception for URDF, this might be a coincidence.

Yep that makes sense, oversight on my part. Thanks for spotting it.

The mesh references in your URDF look for me strange:
<mesh filename="file://$(find robot_description)/meshes/base_link.STL"/>

Normally mesh resources are referenced by the package name and not by the file URL:
<mesh filename="package://name_of_the_package/to/mesh/base_link.STL"/>

While some specific tool may also support your format, this potentially may look like a potential problem.
